# Pegar dados de relatório XML em PHP

Tags: php, xml

Tenho o seguinte relatório no link em XML: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Armaz%C3%A9m,BR&mode=xml

Gostaria apenas de tratá-lo de uma maneira bem simples, tentei utilizando algo como:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Armazem,SC&mode=xml");
echo $xml->temperature;
?>
```

Porém sem sucesso. Qual seria a melhor maneira de lidar com tal relatório?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para acessar o valor no XML você deve chamar o nome da tag e acessar o valor usando foo["value"].
Por exemplo, para:

```
<city id="3469115" name="Armazém">
```

Fica:

```
$xml->city["name"];
```

---

Para ler o `XML` da url informada utilizei o `curl` da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$xml = get_data("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Armazem,SC&mode=xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->temperature["value"];
?>
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: Poderia apenas citar como consigo pegar o country por exemplo neste xml? Fiz da seguinte maneira: || echo $xml->country; || porém não funciona.

Comment: Note que `<country>` está dentro de `<city>` então fica `$xml->city->country;`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Possui a maneira com [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
<?php
    header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $data = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Armazem,SC&mode=xml');
    $xml  = simplexml_load_string($data);

    $cityID       = $xml->city['id'];
    $cityName     = $xml->city['name'];
    $cityCoordLon = $xml->city->coord['lon'];
    $cityCoordLat = $xml->city->coord['lat'];
    $cityCountry  = $xml->city->country;
    $citySunRise  = $xml->city->sun['rise'];
    $citySunSet   = $xml->city->sun['set'];

    $temperatureValue = $xml->temperature['value'];
    $temperatureMin   = $xml->temperature['min'];
    $temperatureMax   = $xml->temperature['max'];
    $temperatureUnit  = $xml->temperature['unit'];

    $humidityValue = $xml->humidity['value'];
    $humidityUnit  = $xml->humidity['unit'];

    $pressureValue = $xml->pressure['value'];
    $pressureUnit  = $xml->pressure['unit'];
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua colaboração também!