# Filtrar determinados elementos de um XML

Tags: php, xml, relatório

Tenho o seguinte relatório de previsão de tempo gerado por uma API de terceiros:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Tubar%C3%A3o,br&mode=xml

Se reparar bem a estrutura temos a previsão setada para cada 3h.

```
<time from="2014-06-15T00:00:00" to="2014-06-15T03:00:00">
<time from="2014-06-15T03:00:00" to="2014-06-15T06:00:00">
<time from="2014-06-15T06:00:00" to="2014-06-15T09:00:00">
```

Gostaria de pegar estes valores individualmente, provável que a melhor maneira é armazená-los em uma array e depois filtrar, algo do tipo.

Alguém tem uma boa solução? Para pegar os dados via XML estou usando a [solução que obtive em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15451/pegar-dados-de-relat%C3%B3rio-xml-em-php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce pode usar [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). Em XPath você pode expressar um caminho dentro de um XML como uma *sequencia de passos*. Cada passo cria um contexto para o passo seguinte. O último passo contém os elementos que você quer selecionar. Os contextos e seleção podem ainda ser filtrados com predicados, que operam no contexto do passo e fazem a seleção com expressões booleanas.

No XML de exemplo que você apresentou, é possível selecionar a cidade com:

```
/weatherdata/location/name
```

A *latitude* está dentro de um *atributo*, que pode ser selecionado com um passo adicional dentro de um *eixo* especial (com prefixo `@`):

```
/weatherdata/location/location/@latitude
```

Você também pode usar *eixos descendentes*, que selecionam vários elementos sem levar em conta contextos intermediários:

```
//location
```

retorna um conjunto contendo dois elementos: o `location` que é filho de `weatherdata` (`/weatherdata/location`), e o outro `location` que é neto de `weatherdata` e filho do primeiro `location` (`/weatherdata/location/location`).

Um predicado pode ser usado para filtrar esses resultados. A expressão:

```
(//location)[2]
```

filtra o conjunto de forma a selecionar apenas o segundo elemento. Os parênteses garantem que a posição é absoluta em relação a todos os elementos localizados (e não à posição de `location` dentro do seu contexto, que é *default*)

No exemplo que você postou, você pode recuperar todos os objetos `time` com uma expressão bem simples:

```
//time
```

Esta expressão retorna um conjunto de nós, que você pode manipular em um *for-each* e extrair o que você quiser deles: valores de atributos, elementos filho, etc. Você também pode realizar expressões XPath *contextuais*. Uma vez *dentro* do contexto do elemento `time`, você pode usar expressões como `precipitation/@value` (que não começam com `/`) para obter o valor do atributo `value` do elemento `precipitation` do objeto `time` selecionado.

O exemplo a seguir lê o documento na URL que você passou, seleciona todos os elementos `time`, e monta uma tabela HTML contendo os atributos `to` e `from`, além de dois atributos do elemento filho `temperature`: `max` e `min`.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Tubar%C3%A3o,br&mode=xml" ); 
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

echo '<table border="1">'."\n";
echo '<tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Temp min</th><th>Temp max</th></tr>'."\n";
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//time") as $time) {
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'.$time->getAttribute('from').'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'.$time->getAttribute('to').'</td>'."\n";
    $temp = $xpath->evaluate('temperature', $time)->item(0);
    echo '<td>'.$temp->getAttribute('min').' '.$temp->getAttribute('unit').'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'.$temp->getAttribute('max').' '.$temp->getAttribute('unit').'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
}
echo '</table>'."\n";

?>
```

Os elementos foram selecionados com XPath, mas os atributos usaram a função `getAttribute()` do XML DOM. Você poderia ter feito tudo com XPath também, por exemplo:

```
$tempMax = $xpath->evaluate('temperature/@max', $time);
```

Os elementos são sempre retornados como *um conjunto*, mesmo que unitário, por isso precisam do `->item(0)` para extrair o primeiro. Os atributos não precisam. Quando a expressão retorna um nó que tem um valor (como um nó de texto), você pode atribuir esse valor a um string usando `->nodeValue`.

O exemplo acima deve servir de ponto de partida para o que você deseja fazer. Veja ele funcionando em tempo real neste **[Fiddle PHP](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NUhhS3)**