# Como procurar um elemento no XML com PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Estou começando à trabalhar com PHP agora, então não sei muita coisa. Por isso, desculpe se a dúvida for muito sem noção.

Eu tenho um arquivo XML tipo assim:

```
<usuários><br>
<fulano>
   <codigo>287983</codigo>
   <pontos>50</pontos>
   <nick>tal1</nick>
</fulano>
<ciclano>
   <codigo>455343</codigo>
   <pontos>80</pontos>
   <nick>tal2</nick>
</ciclano>
<beltrano>
   <codigo>233432</codigo>
   <pontos>60</pontos>
   <nick>tal3</nick>
</beltrano>
</usuarios>
```

Eu queria saber algum evento do PHP que eu pudesse pesquisar um nome do elemento e mostrasse seus pais.
Detalhando melhor o que eu quero fazer. Eu tenho uma caixa de texto onde o visitante irá escrever o nome de usuário e pesquisar por ele. Ai, o script irá procurar no XML o nome que foi digitado em algum dos itens "nick", e assim, retornar o nome dos pais. Caso não ache, que retorne um erro ou algo do tipo.
Por exemplo, alguém digita o nick "tal2" na caixa de texto e pesquisa, o script deve retornar o valor "Ciclano".
O contrário pode ser também, alguém digitar "Ciclano" e receber "tal2" com uma mensagem de erro caso não ache.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Aconselho dar uma olhada aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.xml.php. Depois, essa resposta pode te ajudar também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15452/14674

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o XPath:

Exemplo:

```
$content = "<usuarios>
<fulano>
   <codigo>287983</codigo>
   <pontos>50</pontos>
   <nick>tal1</nick>
</fulano>
<ciclano>
   <codigo>455343</codigo>
   <pontos>80</pontos>
   <nick>tal2</nick>
</ciclano>
<beltrano>
   <codigo>233432</codigo>
   <pontos>60</pontos>
   <nick>tal3</nick>
</beltrano>
</usuarios>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$list = $xml->xpath('//nick');
foreach($list as $nick) {
    if(strpos((string)$nick, 'tal1') !== false) {
        $person = $nick->xpath('..');
        echo "Found person: ";
        var_dump($person);
    }
}
```

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3